# How can i align content inside other flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to have a max 1100px div with spacebetween items but if i center .menu, space between isnt work...

What i can do? (or margin auto?)

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu {
  max-width: 1100px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href=""><img src="https://www.colacao.es/img/logo.png" width="56px" height="50px"></a>
    <div>
      <a href="">Services</a>
      <a href="">Pricing</a>
      <a href="">Blog</a>
      <a href="">Contacts</a>
    </div>
    <a href="">Log In</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change the max-width to width

Comment: remove flex from the outer container

Comment: @IkechukwuEze i need max-width

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, but i want center the .menu div

Comment: remove the outer flex and use margin:auto

Comment: @TemaniAfif not work

Comment: here is : https://jsfiddle.net/pc7tLn9k/

Comment: yes, i had another margin, ty

Comment: Remove max-width and add flex-basis: 500px; https://jsfiddle.net/af2myo5u/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.menu` is a block-level element, it is naturally going to take up the maximum width of the row (100%). Therefore, you can set `max-width` on the element, to limit this behavior and stop at `1100px`, or `100%`, whichever comes first. As Temani mentioned above, you can center the enter element using `margin: auto`. I wrote out the `margin`s longhand, since you are concerned with adding `auto` to only the left and right margins (no need to set top and bottom).

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1100px;  
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href=""><img src="https://www.colacao.es/img/logo.png" width="56px" height="50px"></a>
    <div>
      <a href="">Services</a>
      <a href="">Pricing</a>
      <a href="">Blog</a>
      <a href="">Contacts</a>
    </div>
    <a href="">Log In</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh ty, have sense, its the correct way?

Comment: @Karoly It's one of several ways to do it. There is not one correct way.

Comment: What would be the correct?

Comment: @Karoly I adjusted the answer to the way I would do it (almost identical to Temani). Again, it's one way of many. I don't think the outer flex wrapper is wrong—it's just another way to do it.